# Date Created And Date Closed Field showing #NUM whilst still open

Tags: date

I am using Microsoft sharepoint.

I have 3 fields:
- Date Created
- Date Closed
- Duration

I am trying to work out how to get the duration column to populate whilst the date created field has been populated but date closed has not.

I currently have entered:

=DATEDIF([Created Date],[Completed Date],"d")

This helps only when I enter a completed date, if I don't it comes up with a status of #NUM.

Does anyone know how I can have duration field to also show number of days issue was created whilst the date completed field has not been populated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want displayed when there is missing data? "n/a"? If you want it to display the number of days since created, then Calculated Columns cannot do that. They are calculated when they are created and not updated until the list item is updated. They are not updated on each view.

```
=IF( ISBLANK( [Completed Date] ), "n/a", DATEDIF([Created Date],[Completed Date],"d") )
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is helpful. I will look further to see if I can set it up for all views. Appreciate your help.